# Noise Cancellation on live audio stream

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, audio-processing

I want to build an application which takes a live audio from source (mic) and filtering the noise (unwanted sounds like chattering, traffic noises) and fetch into an application for further processing.

I want to apply Machine Learning Framework (TensorFlow, Keras) and Deep Learning neural Networks (i.e RNN) for filtering the noise from the audio. I want to do this in a real time environment. My inference device will be a Nvidia Jetson Device. Please guide me where I can find the related documents and how to proceed with the project.

If there is any solution available in any website please refer the link.

Comment: did you manage to make any progress on this issue? looking for some pointers on a similar problem.